# MsalUiRequiredException when Microsoft Graph used inside ClaimsTransformation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm creating a ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project and i'm using Openid-Connect with Microsoft to allow users in our organization to login this webservice.

This all works fine, users can authenticate with their microsoft work account and get signed in. Now i would like to add their profile picture to the claim.

However, I can't seem to get my IClaimsTransformation to work. I've made the UserPhotoClaims to try and add the profile picture for the logged in user. If i use the same graph code to get the picture inside a controller, then it works fine.

If i do it inside a ClaimsTransformation then it fails with the following message:

> MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
>
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
>
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable scopes, string authenticationScheme, string tenantId, string userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)

My ClaimsTransformation looks like this:

```
public class UserPhotoClaims : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graph;

    public UserPhotoClaims(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graph = graphServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if(!principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "photo"))
        {
            ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity();

            Stream photo = await _graph.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
            string ps = Convert.ToBase64String((photo as MemoryStream).ToArray());

            id.AddClaim(new Claim("photo", ps));
            principal.AddIdentity(id);
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

And i've added the transformation in my ConfigureServices in startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, UserPhotoClaims>();
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may arise due to permissions not being consented ,as they are already done and  token cache is not called again.

Possible workarounds:

1. Please check if the permissions in the portal are granted consent and try again after adding other scopes in both code and portal and consent them .
2. Clear the cookies , sign out and retry.
3. Try by adding `[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "<TheScopeThatYouArePassingOnAcquireTokenMethod>" })]`  to your action in controller .It processes the MSAL.NET MsalUiRequiredException to handle conditional access and incremental consent.
   Please check [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access#handling-incremental-consent-or-conditional-access-in-web-apps) for more details
4. You may try by Handling the exception using try-catch >see [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/115#issuecomment-632294874)
5. In public client applications ,the design of MSAL.NET is such that AcquireTokenInteractive never looks at the cache. you may need to call AcquireTokenSilent first

```js
 try
    {
     result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
```

6.  Please check this [transforming claims in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation)
and compare the code.

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3)  tutorial that can guide in detail

**References:**

1. [msal-net-acquire-token-silently | Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)
2. [msal-error-handling | Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-dotnet#msaluirequiredexception)
3. [get-microsoft-account-profile-photo-after-login | SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302189/how-to-get-microsoft-account-profile-photo-after-login-with-application-in-mvc)

You may raise a support ticket if workarounds doesn't resolve the issue.